# Elastic Beanstlak CLI Installation Error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip

I downloaded the EBCLI with `sudo pip install awsebcli --upgrade --user`

When running `eb --version` I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andrew/.local/bin/eb", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/setuptools-0.6c11/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/setuptools-0.6c11/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/setuptools-0.6c11/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: awsebcli==3.12.4
```

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

Here is my `pip --version`:

`pip 9.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you installed `awsebcli` as the `root` user, but performed `eb --version` as a non-`root` user. So, as far as the non-`root` user is concerned, `awsebcli` never got installed.

To run `eb` as a non-`root` user:

1. `pip install awsebcli` (without the `sudo`)
2. To verify this worked, find `awsebcli` in the output of `pip list`
3. If 1. causes you a problem, I recommend installing the `awsebcli` after setting up a [`virtualenv`](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/#lower-level-virtualenv). Basically, `virtualenv` compartmentalizes your Python packages so you do not mess with the system's version of Python and the `root` user.