# How to install EB CLI on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, ebcli

I have tried lots of efforts but not found the result.

**Error Showing**

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3088, in <module>
@_call_aside
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3072, in _call_aside
f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3101, in _initialize_master_working_set
working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 574, in _build_master
ws.require(__requires__)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 892, in require
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 778, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'awsebcli==3.12.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Comment: Did you install `eb` as `sudo`, and are you subsequently trying to access `eb` without it?

Comment: Yes! I install `eb` as `sudo`. and when I am trying to access `eb` it showing same error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49782230/elastic-beanstlak-cli-installation-error/49786475#49786475).